# How to download a file from web and assign to the certain folder by using SAS

Tags: sas

Good Morning

So I have tried to download zip file from the website, and try to assign the location.

The location I want to put is

```
S:\Projects\
```

Method1,

First Attempt is below

```
DATA _null_ ;
x 'start https://yehonal.github.io/DownGit/#/home?url=https:%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FCSSEGISandData%2FCOVID-19%2Ftree%2Fmaster%2Fcsse_covid_19_data%2Fcsse_covid_19_daily_reports';
RUN ;
```

Method1, I can download the file, but this automatically downloaded to my Download folder.

Method 2,

so I found out this way.

```
filename out "S:\Projects\csse_covid_19_daily_reports.zip";

proc http
 url='https://yehonal.github.io/DownGit/#/home?url=https:%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FCSSEGISandData%2FCOVID-19%2Ftree%2Fmaster%2Fcsse_covid_19_data%2Fcsse_covid_19_daily_reports'
 method="get" out=out;
run;
```

But the code is not working, not downloading anything.

[image]

how can I download the file from the web and assign to the certain location?

Comment: That may be because of how that service you're using is. Do you have a link to the actual source file?

Comment: @reeza https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports    and I try to download all file by using https://yehonal.github.io/DownGit/#/home

Comment: Do you want to download all the files at once or the latest daily file every day? And do you want to actually download the file or import the data? You could just import the file directly to a SAS data set, ie import from the Github file directly.

Comment: My logic on sas right now, donwload all file

Comment: FYI - the issue was the service download, the file likely isn't ready it takes some time to prep/run the code, so you could also try a sleep step possibly while you wait for it to finish the full download and then download it. Not sure how to do that so I would probably find it faster to work around it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably recommend a macro in this case then (or CALL EXECUTE) but I prefer macros and then calling the macro via CALL EXECUTE. Took about a minute running on SAS Academics on Demand (free cloud service).

```
*set start date for files;
%let start_date = 01-22-2020;

*macro to import data;
%macro importFullData(date);
    *file name reference;
    filename out "/home/fkhurshed/WANT/&date..csv";
    *file to download;
    %let download_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/&date..csv";

    proc http url=&download_url
 method="get" out=out;
    run;

    *You can add in data import/append steps here as well as necessary;
%mend;

%importFullData(&start_date.);

data importAll;
    
    start_date=input("&start_date", mmddyy10.);
    *runs up to previous day;
    end_date=today() - 1;

    do date=start_date to end_date;
        formatted_date=put(date, mmddyyd10.);
        str=catt('%importFullData(', formatted_date, ');');
        call execute(str);
    end;
run;
```

Comment: This is super wonderful, I have coded SAS for 2 years. I should study more. So I can be like you. I really appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The url when viewed in a browser is using javascript in the browser to construct a zip file that is automatically downloaded.  `Proc HTTP` does not run javascript, so will not be able to download the ultimate response which is the constructed zip file, thus you get the 404 message.

The list of the files in the repository can be obtain as json from url

```
https://api.github.com/repos/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/contents/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports
```

The listing data contains the download_url for each csv file.
A download_url will look like

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-22-2020.csv
```

You can download individual files with SAS per @Reeza, or

- use `git` commands or SAS git* functions to download the repository

  - *AFAIK `git archive` for downloading only a specific subfolder of a repository is not available surfaced by github server*
- use `svn` commands to download a specific folder from a git repository

  - requires `svn` be installed (https://subversion.apache.org/) *I used SlikSvn*

Example:

Make some series plots of a response by date from stacked imported downloaded data.

```
options noxwait xsync xmin source;

* use svn to download all files in a subfolder of a git repository;

* local folder for storing data from 
* COVID-19 Data Repository by the Center for Systems Science and Engineering (CSSE) at Johns Hopkins University;

%let covid_data_root = c:\temp\csse;

%let rc = %sysfunc(dcreate(covid,&covid_data_root));
%let download_path = &covid_data_root\covid;

%let repo_subdir_url = https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports;
%let svn_url = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&repo_subdir_url, tree/master, trunk));

%let os_command = svn checkout &svn_url "&download_path";

/*
* uncomment this block to download the (data) files from the repository subfolder;
%sysexec %superq(os_command);
*/

* codegen and execute the PROC IMPORT steps needed to read each csv file downloaded;

libname covid "&covid_data_root.\covid";

filename csvlist pipe "dir /b ""&download_path""";

data _null_;
  infile csvlist length=l;
  length filename $200;
  input filename $varying. l;

  if lowcase(scan(filename,-1,'.')) = 'csv';

  out = 'covid.day_'||translate(scan(filename,1,'.'),'_','-');

  /* 
   * NOTE: Starting 08/11/2020 FIPS data first starts appearing after a few hundred rows.
   * Thus the high GuessingRows 
   */
  template =
  'PROC IMPORT file="#path#\#filename#" replace out=#out# dbms=csv; ' ||
  'GuessingRows = 5000;' ||
  'run;';

  source_code = tranwrd (template, "#path#", "&download_path");
  source_code = tranwrd (source_code, "#filename#", trim(filename));
  source_code = tranwrd (source_code, "#out#", trim(out));

  /* uncomment this line to import each data file */
  *call execute ('%nrstr(' || trim (source_code) || ')');
run;

* memname is always uppercase;
proc contents noprint data=covid._all_ out=meta(where=(memname like 'DAY_%'));
run;

* compute variable lengths for LENGTH statement;
proc sql noprint;
  select 
    catx(' ', name, case when type=2 then '$' else '' end, maxlen)
  into
    :lengths separated by ' '
  from 
  ( select name, min(type) as type, max(length) as maxlen, min(varnum) as minvarnum, max(varnum) as maxvarnum
    from meta
    group by name
  )
  order by minvarnum, maxvarnum
  ;
quit;

* stack all the individual daily data;
data covid.all_days;
  attrib date length=8 format=mmddyy10.;
  length &lengths;
  set covid.day_: indsname=dsname;
  date = input(substr(dsname,11),mmddyy10.);
  format _character_;     * reset length based formats;
  informat _character_;   * reset length based informats; 
run ;

proc sort data=covid.all_days out=us_days;
  where country_region = 'US';
  by province_state admin2 date;
run;

ods html gpath='.' path='.' file='covid.html';

options nobyline;
proc sgplot data=us_days;
  where province_state =: 'Cali';
  *where also admin2=: 'O';

  by province_state admin2;
  title "#byval2 County, #byval1";

  series x=date y=confirmed;
  xaxis valuesformat=monname3.;

  label province_state='State' admin2='County';
  label confirmed='Confirmed (cumulative?)';
run;
  
ods html close;

options byline;
```

Plots
[image]